webgl instancing is not showing anything
using twgl.js to simplify stuff, but for some reason I get this warning:
[.WebGL-000031BC01680600] GL_INVALID_OPERATION: Must have element array buffer bound.

and nothing appears on the screen. However, using instancing examples from the creator of twgl.js work perfectly fine. The goal is to make circles across the screen, each with their own position and size. I dont use webgl much and havent done instancing before though, so Im not sure where I went wrong
also Im using parcel
file structure is fairly simple:
index.html
index.cjs
src/
 | renderer.cjs

renderer.cjs:
const twgl = require("twgl.js")

const VERT_SHADER = `precision mediump float;

attribute vec2 points;
attribute vec2 position;
attribute float size;

uniform vec2 resolution;

void main() {
    vec2 transform = vec2((points * size + position) / resolution);
    vec2 clipSpace = transform * vec2(2.0, -2.0) - vec2(1.0, 1.0);
    gl_Position = vec4(clipSpace, 1.0, 1.0);
}`

const FRAG_SHADER = `precision mediump float;
 
void main() {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(0.19, 0.43, 0.69, 1.0);
}`


module.exports = class {
    arrays = {
        points: {
            numComponents: 2,
            data: [],
        },
        position: {
            numComponents: 2,
            data: [],
            divisor: 1,
        },
        size: {
            numComponents: 1,
            data: [],
            divisor: 1,
        }
    }

    constructor(canvas) {
        this.gl = canvas.getContext("webgl")
        twgl.addExtensionsToContext(this.gl)

        this.programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(this.gl, [VERT_SHADER, FRAG_SHADER])
    }

    setCircleSides(sides) {
        this.sides = sides
        const theta = 2 * Math.PI / sides

        let data = []

        // adding the vertices of the triangles in a circle
        for (let i = 0; i < sides; ++i) {
            data.push(
                0, 0,
                Math.cos(i * theta), Math.sin(i * theta),
                Math.cos((i + 1) * theta), Math.sin((i + 1) * theta),
            )
        }

        this.arrays.points.data = data
    }

    addCircle(x, y, size) {
        this.arrays.position.data.push(x, y)
        this.arrays.size.data.push(size)
    }

    updateBuffers() {
        this.bufferInfo = twgl.createBufferInfoFromArrays(this.gl, this.arrays)
        this.vertexArrayInfo = twgl.createVertexArrayInfo(this.gl, this.programInfo, this.bufferInfo)
    }

    render() {
        this.gl.canvas.width = innerWidth
        this.gl.canvas.height = innerHeight

        twgl.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(this.gl.canvas)
        this.gl.viewport(0, 0, innerWidth, innerHeight)

        this.gl.clear(this.gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | this.gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

        const uniforms = {
            resolution: [innerWidth, innerHeight]
        }

        this.updateBuffers()

        this.gl.useProgram(this.programInfo.program)
        twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(this.gl, this.programInfo, this.vertexArrayInfo)
        twgl.setUniforms(this.programInfo, uniforms)
        this.gl.drawElementsInstanced(this.gl.TRIANGLES, this.vertexArrayInfo.numElements, this.gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0, this.arrays.size.data.length)
    }
}

index.cjs:
const Renderer = require("./src/renderer.cjs")

// using defer in the html, so it runs after elements are loaded
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas")

function main() {
    const renderer = new Renderer(canvas)

    renderer.setCircleSides(8)

    for (let i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        renderer.addCircle(Math.random() * 200, Math.random() * 200, Math.random() * 10)
    }

    renderer.render()
}
main()

The example that I tried which worked perfectly fine is on this post: Use instancing extension in twgl.js
